# Java regex trouble

Tags: java, regex

I have a problem with java regex. I have something like

```
com/products/id/response.html
```

And I want the id as anything from Aa-Zz 0-9, I have tried:

```
com/products/A-Za-z0-9]+/response.html
```

However with no success, but in this case

```
com/products/A-Za-z0-9]+.html
```

It works just fine...
Any idea where Am I making mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Character class is `[...]` and you have missing `[`
- You need to escape dot
- Jave needs `\\` for escaping

You can use this regex:

```
com/products/[A-Za-z0-9]+/response\\.html
```

- You may need to use anchors `^` and `$` also.

Comment: I tend to do [.] so I don't shoot myself in the foot with \\.

Comment: Also, if you try to use this regex in sed, Javascript, or Perl, the forward slashes need escaping, too.

Comment: Yes that's correct about Javascript but you can use an alternative delimiter in Perl/sed to avoid escaping in substitute commands.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me out, however it still doesn't seem to work

Comment: I have tested is separately and It works, seems like there is something wrong with my other components that make this fail. Thank you for answer

Answer (score 0):

You missed the first parentheses, so it need to look like this:

```
com/products/[A-Za-z0-9]+/response[.]html
```